# Could you please reopen my question asking privileges please?

Tags: support, questions

I’m trying to improve my question asking abilities, but I can’t do it if I can’t ask questions, could someone please reopen my question asking privileges please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We **cannot**. Moderators are not given the power to lift an automatic question ban — as explained in the mod message we sent you.

Please see [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)

Comment: And allow me to add - that link and explanation, as well as many links about how to improve, have been sent to you several times in mod messages.  Consider reading them if you actually intend to improve.